# Checking to see if TIF and PNG are the exact same

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tiff, geotiff

I am having issues finding the best Pythonic way to check if a file of type TIF (or TIFF) is exactly the same as a PNG.

I currently have a program that converts GeoTIFF files into PNG format keeping the same dimensions. I want to test whether the conversion is happening correctly and the TIF/TIFF and PNG are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You could use imagehash to check the similarity of the images:

```
from PIL import Image
import imagehash

hash1 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('image_tiff.tiff'))
hash2 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('image_png.png'))

if hash1 - hash2 < 6:
  print('Similar')
else:
  print('Not Similar')
```

The value '6' is something like a threshold for the maximum number of bits that can be different between both images. Since pillow fully supports both TIFF and PNG formats, you shouldn't be having problems opening those files.